# how to filter all items which do not have a certain attribute in dynamodb using java?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

As per my requirement, i have to filter all items which dont have certain attributes in dynamo db. I have written the scan query with Condition in it. Below is the code for it.

```
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName);
            Condition condition1 = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NULL);
            for (String param : params) {
                scanRequest.addScanFilterEntry(param, condition1);
            }

            ScanResult scan = amazonDynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
```

This code is working fine and gives desired result to me. Only concern point here is that we are using scan and scan consider the whole table for scanning. If there are lots of records in table then scan may impact the performance of it and also scanning operation consume the read capacity in dynamo.

So is there any other efficient way to filter all items which dont have some attributes in dynamo db.

Thanks